# structure theorem for modules

Tags: modules, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Can structure theorem for modules be extended to modules over UFDS , to modules over Neotherian rings ? if yes then can one get the statement and reference?

Since operations on matrices with coefficients as polynomials in several variables some extension seems possible .

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to the structure of modules over
a principal ideal domain? A complete classification of modules over a polynomial ring in $2$ variables is already very difficult,
but a lot is known.
What sort of answer were you hoping for?


Comment: To add to Donu's comment in the spirit of unknown's answer: the finite-length modules over $k[x,y]$ are of wild representation type -- they can't be parametrized by the points of any finite-dimensional variety. Put another way, a classification of those modules would entail a classification of \emph{all} modules over \emph{every} finite-dimensional $k$-algebra.  So: hopeless.  The result about $k[x,y]$ is due to Drozd, I think. 

Comment: A reference for the result on $k[x,y]$ is [I. M. Gelfand and V. A. Ponomarev, Remarks on the classification of a pair of commuting linear transformations in a finite dimensional vector space, Functional Anal. Appl. 3 (1969) 325-326.] They prove that classifying artinian modules over $k[x,y]$ is as hard as classifying modules over a free algebra on three generators. Drozd's work implies this last problem is wild.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me start by something classical: extending the classical result for PIDs, by Steinitz's Theorem (1912) all finitely generated modules over Dedekind domains are characterized, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domains and scroll down.

Beyond Dedekind domains things get complicated, but there is considerable recent work going on. The following [paper](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~levy/preprints/Levy%2DLisbon%2Dfinal.pdf) by Levy and Klingler gives an overview on their expansive (recent) work on this. Very roughly, there is a tame/wild dichotomy (very informally 'wild' is more or less 'hopeless') and they give an (essentially) complete answer for those noetherian rings were the answer is not 'wild'; the key-word here is Dedekind-like.
The 'essential' refers to the fact that, as they point out, there are or at least might be some exceptions in some characteristic two cases.

I am convinced that I once saw some subsequent work on this particular cases (though I do not remember whether it was partial or complete), yet unfortunately I am unable to find it right now.